# Does Partial tag helper use RenderPartialAsync or PartialAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

In ASP.Net Core there is tag helper for rendering partial views in main views.
but i can't find anywhere that whether the Partial Tag helper uses RenderPartialAsync or PartialAsync behind the hood
i am asking this because performance wise RenderPartialAsync is better then PartialAsync .

Comment: Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Comment: actually my question hasn't been answered yet...you said partialTag uses HtmlHelperPartialExtensions  then again which one is invoked on what basis or on which particular condition

Comment: `Which one is invoked on what basis or on which particular condition`, it totally ups to the user, what user wants to use, the scenarios are "when we need to runs simultaneous partial action then we should use `PartialAsync`"  On the contrary, we should use `RenderPartialAsync` when single partial action need to invoke. Hope you got the points now. Let me know if you still has confusion.

Comment: i don't know if i am confusing you or something..but i am asking how do i achieve this with **TAG** Helper and you are telling me to do with **HTML** helper and i know how to do that

Comment: Well, did you gone through the link I have referred? Whats your current concern? Would you kindly add your scenario here? Because `Partial Tag` uses both base on the user implementation. If you still have confusion feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/PartialTagHelper.cs), it seems to be using [`IView.RenderAsync(ViewContext)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewengines.iview.renderasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Maybe it's comparing apples with oranges. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0), it seem to be a replacement for both.

Answer (score 0):

***Does Partial tag helper use RenderPartialAsync or PartialAsync?***

***`Anserws:`*** Well , there are some misconceptions about the two html helper extensions. `Partial tag` neither  uses `PartialAsync` nor `RenderPartialAsync` its uses `HtmlHelperPartialExtensions` which contains all the partial helpers. You could have look on below:

[image]

***Diffrence:***

***`PartialAsync`*** Returns
`A System.Threading.Tasks.Task that on completion returns a new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent instance containing the created HTML`.

***`RenderPartialAsync`*** Returns `A System.Threading.Tasks.Task that renders the created HTML when it executes`

***Similarity:***

Both can pass `ViewDataDictionary` so when you invoke any `Partial tag` it will call the `HtmlHelperPartialExtensions`.

***Which one more performance efficient:***

[`PartialAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperpartialextensions.partialasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) can run list of task together without any deadlock `Task<IHtmlContent>`

On the other hand [`RenderPartialAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperpartialextensions.renderpartialasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) runs a single thread `Task RenderPartialAsync`. But its depends up to your requirement and needs.

***Note:*** Hope it would help you to leverage your concept. If you still want to gain some more idea you could have a look our [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0#asynchronous-html-helper). For `RenderPartialAsync` you can [have a look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperpartialextensions.renderpartialasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0)